# Order is getting changed in Copy-Paste of selected row in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have written below code to put only selected datagridview rows into clipboard text.

`

```
            Dim ClipBoardBuilder As New StringBuilder()

            For Each row As DataGridViewRow In MyRows
                For Each Column As DataGridViewColumn In dgv1.Columns
                    If Column.Visible = True Then ClipBoardBuilder.Append(row.Cells(Column.DisplayIndex).FormattedValue.ToString() + vbTab)
                Next
                ClipBoardBuilder.AppendLine()
            Next

            If dgv1.GetClipboardContent() IsNot Nothing Then Clipboard.SetText(ClipBoardBuilder.ToString())


            Dim ClipBoardText as string = Clipboard.GetText()
```

`

but the order of selected row is getting changed while pasting it in grid.
for example

 `row1 - A1 B1 C1
 row2 - A2 B2 C2
 row3 - A3 B3 C3`

then in clip board it is shown as just opposite like below and getting pasted in grid in same as shown below

 `row3 - A3 B3 C3
 row2 - A2 B2 C2
 row1 - A1 B1 C1`

how to make the order sequence as original is while pasting in grid.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

you can sort your gridview.

```
DataGridView1.Sort(DataGridView1.Columns(1), ListSortDirection.Ascending)
```

Comment: sorry for wrong interpretation. i am asking that why after putting in string buildder and then putting in ClipBoard the order is getting changed?

because after pasting same copied row in same grid, order is getting changed.

copy order
`
row1
row2
row3
`
but paste order is 
`
row3
row2
row1
`

why?

Comment: sorry @picnic4u I am assumed wrongly. but i have go through your code. For me clipboard text order is not getting changed. its show in correct order for me

Answer (score 0):

Here I am iterating through the selected rows and selected rows is coming in the selected sequence order.

if user selects 1st row then 3rd row then 2nd row. in that case the selected row will be there as per their selection order in the row collection means
1st row 
3rd row
2nd row

so while i am coping in the clipboard using string builder then it is getting copied as per selected sequence order but not as per assending row index order

so for this before iterating i am sorting the selected rows in the assending index order as below.

`Dim dgvRows As List(Of DataGridViewRow) = (From c As DataGridViewRow In 
                                           dgv1.SelectedRows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
                                           Select c                                                            Order By c.Index).Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)().ToList`

Now it is getting pasted in desired order only.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing there is confusion as to how the `DataGridView`s selected rows is organized. The `SelectedRows` returns a `DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection`.  As you noticed the order of this collection is such that the LAST selected row is at index zero (0) in the collection and the FIRST selected row is at the LAST index of the collection.

If you want to get the original order the user selected the rows, you could reverse the collection or you could simply loop through the collection starting from the last index to the first. This will get the original order that the user selected the rows.

Bear in mind that you cannot assume the user will select rows in a top-down fashion. The user can select row 2, then row 9, then row 4, then row 3. Depending on what you are doing this may be acceptable, however if you are deleting the selected rows, then you will need to sort the collection such that the rows are in consecutive order. Since it is not clear what you are doing with these selected rows, I will assume deleting the rows is not what you are doing.

Below is a simple example of how to get the original order of the selected rows. NOTE: the `SelectionMode` of the `DataGridView` should be set to `FullRowSelect`. Hope this may clear things up.

[image]

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  FillGrid()
End Sub

Private Sub FillGrid()
  For i = 1 To 15
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("Row" + i.ToString() + "C1", "Row" + i.ToString() + "C2", "Row" + i.ToString() + "C3")
  Next
End Sub

Private Sub btSelectedRows_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btSelectedRows.Click
  TextBox1.Text += "Reverse selected values --------" + Environment.NewLine
  TextBox1.Text += "There are " + DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString() + " selected Rows" + Environment.NewLine
  For Each curSelectedRow As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    If Not curSelectedRow.IsNewRow Then  ' ignore new row if selected
      TextBox1.Text += curSelectedRow.Cells(0).Value + ", " + curSelectedRow.Cells(1).Value + ", " + curSelectedRow.Cells(2).Value + Environment.NewLine
    End If
  Next
  TextBox1.Text += "End of Reverse selected values --------" + Environment.NewLine
End Sub

Private Sub btOriginalSelection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btOriginalSelection.Click
  TextBox1.Text += "Original order of selected values --------" + Environment.NewLine
  TextBox1.Text += "There are " + DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count.ToString() + " selected Rows" + Environment.NewLine
  Dim selectedRows As DataGridViewSelectedRowCollection = DataGridView1.SelectedRows
  For rowIndex = selectedRows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Not selectedRows(rowIndex).IsNewRow Then  ' ignore new row if selected
      TextBox1.Text += selectedRows(rowIndex).Cells(0).Value + ", " + selectedRows(rowIndex).Cells(1).Value + ", " +
                       selectedRows(rowIndex).Cells(2).Value + Environment.NewLine
    End If
  Next
  TextBox1.Text += "End of Original selection order of selected values --------"
End Sub
```

End Class